# Store ng-repeat values as array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Good day, I have a simple ng-repeat iterating through an array of objects. here is a snippet of the html code:

```
 <div ng-repeat="coapplicant in coapplicants">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Joint Holder ID</label>
                    <input type="text" name="joint_holder_id" class="form-control" ng-model="coapplicant.joint_holder_id">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Notes</label>
                    <textarea name="notes" class="form-control" ng-model="coapplicant.notes"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Relation Code</label>
                    <select name="relation_code" class="form-control" ng-model="coapplicant.relation_code" ng-options="rcode.key as rcode.value for rcode in relation_code track by rcode.key">
                        <option value="">Select Relation Code</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Also here is the array of objects I am looping through:

```
[{joint_holder_id:23232},{joint_holder_id:222323}]
```

If you kindly look back on the first code snippet, the user should add information in the notes textarea and select a relational code.I want get those values and store in a variable as an array of objects. So, how could achieve this? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What is not working? It should already have been add  into your array.

Comment: @Deblaton Jean-Philippe, I want to get ng-repeat values that user entered in the form to be variable in controller

Comment: As @DeblatonJean-Philippe said, that's already done by the 2 way data binding of angular js. As you use `ng-model` on `coapplicants` sub variables, it's normaly be updated ;)

Comment: your code [works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tmCIyuBGIO7LwtM5LSwO?p=preview) . Not clear what problem is

Comment: Did you add your controller to the html higher up in your code?  I know I've forgot to add the controller before and couldn't figure out why my code wasn't working.

Comment: Well then..., thanks guys